# How do I eliminate space between the box in html/css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my output looks better, I have upload file function. After user have uploaded their file I will display/preview the file for the user before they submitting their form. How do I make this output better and I want to know is there any way for me to eliminate the spaces/gap between the box ?

[image: How do I eliminate gap in the highlight between the box ?]

```
  <div class="tab-content col-12 mt-4" id="myTabContent-2">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="addCustodian" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="addCustodian-tab">
     <div class="col-md-12" id="item_${index}" data-ind="${index}">   
       <div class="container p-1 my-1 border">
           <ul>
              <li class="align-items-center">
                <div>
                  <span class='close' onclick='deleteFile(${index})'>&times;</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                 <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:black;"><p class="mb-0 font-size-12"> ${name}</p></a>
                </div>
              </li>
         </ul>
       </div>  
      </div>  
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: That's either margin or padding. Set them to zero. Use the dev tools to find out. It's got a nice tool for hovering the element. If the space is green, it's padding. Orange is margin.

Comment: I don't think that the code you posted is closely related to the screenshot. You can use the development tools of your browser to inspect the elements and see where the gap is comming from.

Comment: can you share your complete code ? with CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think you are looking something like this**

You need to remove `mt-4` from your second box.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
  

<div class="tab-content col-12  mt-3" id="myTabContent-2">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="addCustodian" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="addCustodian-tab">
   <div class="col-md-12" id="item_${index}" data-ind="${index}">   
     <div class="container p-1 border">
         <ul>
            <li class="align-items-center">
              <div>
                <span class='close' onclick='deleteFile(${index})'>&times;</span>
              </div>
              <div>
               <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:black;"><p class="mb-0 font-size-12"> ${name}</p></a>
              </div>
            </li>
            
       </ul>
       
     </div>  
     <div class="container p-1 border">
      <ul>
         <li class="align-items-center">
           <div>
             <span class='close' onclick='deleteFile(${index})'>&times;</span>
           </div>
           <div>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:black;"><p class="mb-0 font-size-12"> ${name}</p></a>
           </div>
         </li>
         
    </ul>
    
  </div>  
    </div>  
   </div>
 </div> 
  

</body>
</html>
```

**Import your `CDN` to make your closing functionally**

**Let me know if this will work for you.**

Comment: it did reduce the gap, not completely close. But I will make it work. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

For greater efficiency you can use developer tools in chrome/safari/firefox and see where you have extra margin/padding.  I can propose that you need add "mb-0" class into  to have .
If its will not help, better to share link to site / git.